# Lambda Function Serverless permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, aws-lambda

I've been developing an aws lambda function with python and serverless. It reads files from a s3 bucket and stores data from it in another bucket as a csv. The code works perfectly with invoke local but after deploying I get:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

This is the function:

```
s3_client.put_object(Body=data, Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key_name)
```

and part of the serverless yml

```
iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
Action:
    - KMS:Decrypt
Resource: '*'
    - Effect: Allow
Action:
    - 's3:*'
Resource:
    - 'arn:aws:s3:::output_bucket'
    - 'arn:aws:s3:::output_bucket/*'
- Effect: Allow
Action:
    - 's3:ListBucket'
Resource:
    - 'arn:aws:s3:::input_bucket'
    - 'arn:aws:s3:::input_bucket/*'       

- Effect: Allow
    Action:
    - 's3:GetObject'
Resource:
    - 'arn:aws:s3:::input_bucket'
    - 'arn:aws:s3:::input_bucket/*'
```

Is there any other configuration I need? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: lambda has a role attached, that role should have access to s3, can you check that?

Comment: @GowthamChand how can I check that? the error is on `s3_client = boto3.client('s3')` cos I don't have the credentials, do you know how can I pass it by the .yml file?

Answer (score 1):

For me the indent looks wrong. Please make sure to use it right.

```
iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - 'kms:Decrypt'
    Resource: '*'
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - 's3:*'
    Resource:
      - 'arn:aws:s3:::output_bucket'
      - 'arn:aws:s3:::output_bucket/*'
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - 's3:ListBucket'
      - 's3:GetObject'
    Resource:
      - 'arn:aws:s3:::input_bucket'
      - 'arn:aws:s3:::input_bucket/*'
```

FYI: I merged `s3:ListBucket` and `s3:GetObject` into one statement.